# Problem involving Bilinear Forms from Micheal Artin's book.

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

The question is:
Let T be a linear operator on $V=R^n$ whose matrix $A$ is a real symmetricmatrix.

a) Prove that $V$ is the orthogonal sum $V=(ker T)\oplus(im T)$

b) Prove that $T$ is an orthogonal projection onto $imT$ if and only if, in addition to being symmetric, $A^2=A$.

I can not understand the question very well, $T$ is a linear operation on vector space, then it will operate on some vector $v$ in $V$, then what is kernal of $T$, how can $Tv=1$ in a vector space?

Comment: The kernel for linear transformation is the set/subspace of elements sent to the zero vector.

Comment: Thank you @DavidP, I can understand a vector $v$ can either in $kerT$ or in $imT$ then, that prove the first question. And in the second question, the $A^2=A$, is it mean $A=I$ or it have some additional information?

Comment: No, A definitely does not have to be I... did you take a basic linear class before attempting this one? Are you self learning?

Comment: Hi, @DavidP. Yes, I am self learning, I took some basic linear classes many years before, maybe I forgot some things.